# Interpolete from dabase field

Tags: node.js, string-interpolation

I'm writing code on many users reply to your customers. Every user can write your custom message with few arguments.
I like make every user can define on your profile, one "programatic" string, like this:

`Hi, i'm ${user.name}. See the attached message`

`Hi, i'm ${user.name}, your total amount of credit here is ${customer.totalCredit}, now you have compromissed ${customer.compromissed}.`

But, how i can make the interpolation is "translated" from database string on my nodejs code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm find the solution.

```
eval(`\`${user.customMessage}\``);
```

with this, it works fine :D